# How do I make a template function?

Tags: php

```
//TEMPLATE FILE
<html>
f_blog_title();
</html>
//TEMPLATE LOAD
<?php
ob_start();
echo file_get_contents('TEMPLATE FILE');
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Now my problem is, how to search f_???() and run ??? function?

Comment: Wait a minute, what's the question?

Comment: I want to run blog_title() function :D

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to build your own templating system, maybe you should look at existing ones and learn from the way they do it; [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/sampleapp/sampleapp_p1.php) seems most accessible for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty sucks - it does not force you to keep logic out of output and you'll be finaly creating code with compromises.

Try some fully XMLized as http://phptal.org/ it's actualy my choice to be honest.
It's very clean and very easy to use.
And the most important thing - it force you to keep logic in Your PHP code outside of templates.